# Fetch data in only one key object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an array of objects stored in a `currentCoins` state as follows:

```js
const [currentCoins, setCurrentCoins] = useState([])
    
console.log(currentCoins)

[
    {
        "name": "algorand",
        "quantity": 1,
        "currentPrice": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "ethereum",
        "quantity": 9,
        "currentPrice": 0
    },
    {
        "quantity": 4,
        "name": "bitcoin",
        "currentPrice": 0
    }
]
```

I would like to add a dynamic value from an API in my `currentPrice`, but I'm not sure how to go about and organize this.

I had thought of something like this but it's incomplete, and I don't know how to pass the `name` to the API

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentCoins(coinsCopy) // update currentCoins array from another array that can be updated by the user 

    const fetchPrices = async (name) => {
      await fetch(
        `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${name}`
      )
       // this endpoint returns the current price to res.market_data.current_price.usd

        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          // processing here?
        });
    };
    fetchPrices();
  }, [coins])
```

Processing should be added to the `"// processing here?`comment or am I going in the wrong direction?

The goal would be for this to override the `"0"` value of `currentPrice` for each of my objects.

Comment: what are you getting from api and what are you passing as name

Comment: what do you want to do with that data. i dont see a price anywhere

Comment: the name in fetchPrices function Should be "algorand", "ethereum" and "bitcoin" in my objects list.

Comment: you can indeed change the current price where you mentioned but where do you get the values. i do not see anything related to price in API response

Comment: Yes sorry, i've uptated my 1st post. The correct endpoint is https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${name}

The price is accessible in `market_data.current_price.usd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentCoins(coinsCopy) // update currentCoins array from another array that can be updated by the user 
    fetchPrices();
  }, [coins])


    const fetchPrices = async () => {
      var copyArray = [...currentCoins];
      for(let c of copyArray ){
          var res = await fetch(
           `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${c.name}`
           )
          if(res.ok){
           var data = await res.json()
           var currentPriceUSD = data.market_data.current_price.usd
           c.currentPrice =  currentPriceUSD 
          }else{
            console.log("Cannot find the coin");
          }
   }
      setCurrentCoins(copyArray)

    };
```

Comment: Thanks but how to make the name parameter dynamic? I don't know it until I loop in `// processing here`. So I can't make the endpoint dynamic as it is.

Comment: Ok but what do you want your name parameter to be initially in use state.

Comment: I don't believe. In fact, it will have to pass 3 times (because I have 3 objects in my array of objects) with in 1st: "algorand", then "ethereum" then "bitcoin" following the order of the array.

Then I display a simple loop of my `currentCoins` state to display all the data. The name, quantity and current price.

Comment: Use async await to loop through all the coins you already have and call API to update you state. See the edited answer